# How to pass carriage return via passedArgs in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, parameter-passing

I have a problem when trying to pass a parameter to another function of my controller in CakePHP.

First, I collect a field from textarea of a form in view, in the controller function (`$this->request->data[...]`). Once i have this parameter (string), I want to pass it to another function in same controller. No problem, i use redirect and pass the parameter as `$this->redirect(array('action' => 'function2', 'param1'=>$data1, 'param2'=>$data2...` and get it in the `function2` with `$this->passedArgs`.

The problem comes when the string parameter (collected from textarea) has a line break (carriage return) inside it. It seems like CakePHP doesn't accept URL routes like `myproject/function2/param1:hi**%0D%0A**bye/param2:...` -- I mean with special hexadecimal characters inside it, like `%0D%0A` (line break).

So, the question is: **is there any way to pass these parameters when it contains any special hexadecimal characters like carriage return?**

I thought also passing it like get parameter via `?param1=data1` -- I have tested it and it works, but I think it's more elegant to pass arguments to the function instead of passing via `GET`.

Comment: Don't use named params anymore in 2.x, use query strings. See [here](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/) why.

Comment: @mark Wow! So cool explanation in that blog! Just what i wanted, know why cant pass named parameters with special characters ("The encoding of named params can break urls.") and what to use instead. Seems i was not the only one with the problem :D. Also it says that named params will be outdated in next versions of CakePHP, so I will have to change where this params appear to query strings. These are simply GET params, only that Cake manage them in a "standarized" way, no? Getting them as `$this->request->query` and so. thank you very much, you've help me a lot.(write it as an answer to vote).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As referred to in the comment above it is adviced not to use named params anymore in CakePHP2.x. They are a faulty implementation.
Use query strings instead which will resolve all issues around the encoding.

Additionally, query strings are the way to go in future versions of CakePHP, so additional pain in upgrading can be avoided if one doesn't use deprecated functionality anymore.

For details see [this article](http://www.dereuromark.de/2013/05/04/passed-named-or-query-string-params/).

Comment: As I said, thank you very much! That helped me a lot, and I have solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

`\n` for newline -- 
`\r` for Carriage Return ---

This ought to solve your problem, but note that those need to be in double-quotes in order to work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think it would be better to migrate to "query strings" instead of named params, as @mark says. Thanks anyway mate!